# Unique server assigned MailItem ID among all outlook user

Tags: vba, outlook, office-interop

When an email is sent to multiple recipients, when they receive that mail in their outlook running on their PC, which ID is unique in the sense that it will be the same for all recipients in their outlook?

MailItem.EntryID and MailItem.ConversationID are "locally" unique.